# SQL Server bulk insert type mismatch error from csv

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, csv

I am trying to import data from a tsv (tab separated values) file into a table using SQL Server and Visual Studio, and I am encountering an error that I can't seem to fix. I was able to recreate a small example of how my DB is, and to sort of mimic the issue I am encountering.

I created a new table in my database with the following properties from the .sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [variable1] INT NULL, 
    [variable2] INT NULL, 
    [variable3] INT NULL
)
```

I'd like the ID to be auto-generated whenever a row is added to the table. For my post-deployment script I am reading in the tsv file:

```
BULK INSERT TestTable
FROM 'C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\testData.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\me\Documents\projects\testDataError.txt'
)
```

And this is my data file separated by tabs:

```
11  11  11
22  22  22
33  33  33
```

And lastly the errors I am getting:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 3 (variable2).
>
> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I'm mostly concerned with the first error, by any advice on the other errors as well would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit: Hex file added [hex info for data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBXkr.png)

ErrorFile printed to testDataError.txt

```
11  11  11
22  22  22
33  33  33
33  33  33
```

Edit: Second hex file added for data file
[Second Hex Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfWre.png)

Comment: Hard to say for sure but my bet is that your input file has unexpected character(s) in it between the two values. For this input, all SQL expects between the two columns is a tab.  I'd use a hex editor and take a look at the file. You should also make sure the row's end with just a newline (\n) as \r\n is the Windows standard.

Comment: I found an online hex file editor and attached a link to it in the question. Do the dots in the right column between the data values represent characters in the file?

Comment: The file isn't even close to your spec's. Check out http://www.asciitable.com to understand the values.

Comment: I loaded the data into an excel spreadsheet and then exported it to another tsv, and this is the resulting new hex dump. This seems more in line with what should be expected and What I want. However, it does look like there is a carriage return character before the new line character, and I would like it to be just the new line character, correct?

Comment: If your source is a file from windows, I'd make the ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n' as that is the standard, Windows line terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 4 columns including the primary key column, you have to provide data for all four columns. Hence the first one is **IDENTITY** column, you can provide any value for that column as this column value will not be used but ommitted.

In your case if you provide data like it will work:

```
1   11  11  11
1   22  22  22
1   33  55  66
```

I have checked this and found it works. If you don't have any option to alter the csv file then you can create a staging table without the identity column and perform the bulk insert operation. After that, you can move data from your staging to target table by performing INSERT INTO command. I hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Then don't forget to mark this as an answer. :-) @ans